# Access JavaScript variables with Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm wondering if it's possible to access page JavaScript variables with Selenium. I have an application that's using a variable attached to the window object. It has a global scope and I can access it either with `window._myvar`, `window['_myvar']`, `_myvar`, `this['_myvar']`, `this._myvar` depending on the context.

So I tried to get Selenium to echo it. As far as I understand, in Selenium IDE the context in which everything runs is `selenium`. I tried doing `this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()._myvar`, `this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()[_myvar]` to no avail. I get bumped with the following error `Unexpected Exception: message -> eval(match[1]) is undefined`.

Anyone managed to access their page's JavaScript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to get variables using the getUserWindow rather than getCurrentWindow. See the following example:

```
assertEval | this.browserbot.getUserWindow().myVar | Hello World!
```

Comment: Doh! totally forgot about getUserWindow(). Deleting my answer

Comment: Does the target parameter need to be wrapped in javascript {...}?