# Check javascript error in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have Selenium tests in PHP under PHPUnit run via CruiseControl. Is it somehow possible to check if there was a JavaScript error on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible with CruiseControl to run the test in an ie? If so, you can set the ie to pop up an error message each time a JavaScript error accours. That might time out the test (and fail).
Maybe you can configure the browser you run to pop up a message, also.

Or you render some JavaScript at the end of each page that you want to check and assert that you can access that part. Maybe like described in [Access JavaScript variables with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420413/access-javascript-variables-with-selenium-ide)
This will fail if you have an JavaScript error on the page.