# Accessing Javascript global variables from Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using the latest Selenium IDE 2.2.0,

and I'm having trouble trying to access a javascript global variable that I set in my script.

This variable acts as a success flag, so I've put

```
Command: waitForCondition
Target: test
Value: 2000
```

But I get

```
[error] test is not defined
```

I've tried looking at [Access JavaScript variables with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420413/access-javascript-variables-with-selenium-ide), replacing

```
Target: this.browserbot.getUserWindow().test
```

but I also get

```
[error] this.browserbot is undefined
```

I could try a different method of setting a success flag like throwing out an alert, but I'd like to know how to access my javascript variables.

The docs mentioned storedVars, but that was only for variables stored in selenium so I'm at my wits' end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around a bit more and found the following documentation for

```
Command: waitForEval

Note that, by default, the snippet will run in the context of the "selenium" object
itself, so this will refer to the Selenium object. Use window to refer to the window 
of your application, e.g. window.document.getElementById('foo')

If you need to use a locator to refer to a single element in your application page, 
you can use this.browserbot.findElement("id=foo") where "id=foo" is your locator.
```

And so

```
window.test
```

works!