# Accessing javascript from selenium in django

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, selenium-chromedriver

How can i link up with javascript from a website and make use of some function from the website through selenium. I am using django
I have been able to access some of the elements in dom such as class name etc. But I do not know how to access javascript that is loaded
by the website

I have tried [Accessing Javascript global variables from Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970150/accessing-javascript-global-variables-from-selenium-ide) but it did not give me what I was expecting