# Is it still possible to access javascript variables with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am working on tests using the selenium IDE extension for chrome and I have basically the same problem as in this question [Access JavaScript variables with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420413/access-javascript-variables-with-selenium-ide)

Using `this.browserbot.getUserWindow()` didn't work at all to get my defined variable and as the question I mentioned is 8 years old, I was wondering if there weren't some updates I missed.

I also looked at the recent documentation https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands and I couldn't find the assertEval command they mention in the question.

I am wondering if the run script command is there for that purpose.

To summarize:

- Assuming that I defined an array in the `window` variable like this `window.data=['hello', 'world']` what would be the correct syntax to fetch it during my test?
- What is the difference between those two commands? `execute script` and `run script`
- Is there a more detailed documentation about how to get along with js? I couldn't find where the `this.browserbot` variable came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to help on this one as I've used Arrays in IDE. Array creation is done in JS, but there's different ways it's stored in JS and in Selenium and then manipulated upon. To answer  point 2, Execute Script is what i always as it calls JS but then completes it in the IDE framework, e.g. can store it in Selenium. Run Script only does it in JS and does not return a log with IDE. To answer point 1 and the whole question:

#### Method 1

To create a Selenium IDE array, use the JS execute script command and that will enable storing as a Selenium IDE variable only, here's a basic version of that:

```
Command:   execute script
Target:    return ["hello","world"]
Value:     myArray
```

To check this, add a 2nd command to check the Selenium variable is correctly stored and displays right result in the IDE log:

```
Command:   echo
Target:    ${myArray}
```

#### Method 2

If you already have an array defined in JS, e.g. let myJSArray = ["hello", "world"] or window.myJSArray = ["hello", "world"], and it's defined in the window that Selenium already has open, then you can store that in Selenium using:

```
Command:   execute script
Target:    return myJSArray | Target:    return window.myJSArray
Value:     myArray
```

Then double check it's worked by using the same echo command above

#### Method 3

If you haven't got the window open and you want to store the variable both in JS and in Selenium, then

```
Command:   execute script
Target:    return myJSArray = ["hello","world"] | Target:    return window.myJSArray = ["hello","world"]
Value:     myArray
```

Then again use the echo command to check it's worked.

**In summary - Method 1 stores the array in Selenium only (using JS to achieve it), Method 2 stores an already stored JS variable in the open window to Selenium, Method 3 stores the variable both in JS window and Selenium.**

Depending on the method used, you can then do asserts on the variable (JS one or Selenium one) or even use them in If/Else, loops or general JS functions. If you are using the Selenium variable for any JS scripts of if/else etc, you need to add the ${} to it, if using the JS variable then can call it without the dollar. Example of an Assert using Method 3 for both the Selenium myArray variable or the JS myJSArray variable:

```
Command:   execute script
Target:    return myJSArray = ["hello","world"]
Value:     myArray

//Now have 2 variables, 1. myJSArray that the browser can use; and 2. myArray that Selenium can use. Below to assert either variable contains the array item "world":

Command:   execute script
Target:    return ${myArray}.includes("world")
Value:     myArrayIncludesWorld

Command:   assert
Target:    myArrayIncludesWorld
Value:     true


Command:   execute script
Target:    return myJSArray.includes("world")
Value:     myJSArrayIncludesWorld

Command:   assert
Target:    myJSArrayIncludesWorld
Value:     true
```